# Crypto provider is null

Tags: winnovative

We're seeing this error when generating PDFs using Winnovative's HtmlToPdfConverter:

```
System.Exception
Message: The crypto provider is null
wnvinternal.ᤐ.ᢀ(String A_0):348
wnvinternal.ᤑ.ᜒ(String A_0):165
wnvinternal.ᤑ.ᜀ(String A_0):165
Winnovative.HtmlToPdfConverter.ᜀ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4):1489
Winnovative.HtmlToPdfConverter.ᜀ(Stream A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, String A_4, Boolean A_5)
Winnovative.HtmlToPdfConverter.ᜁ(String A_0, String A_1, String A_2, String A_3, Boolean A_4):62
Winnovative.HtmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(String htmlString, String baseUrl, String internalLinksBaseUrl)
Winnovative.HtmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtml(String htmlString, String baseUrl)
```

What can I do to fix the problem?

**Background**

We have two "production" URLs: one of them is https://ourdomain.com, the other is https://api.ourdomain.com.  These are IIS sites served by two separate VMs.  Identical code is deployed to each, and almost-identical configuration.

There are some difference between the sites.  API has an IP allowlist set on the firewall.  API has 16GB of memoray compared to 32GB on non-API.

The user browses to a URL which returns a PDF file.  On the non-API site, it works as intended: the PDF is available for download.  On the API site, the PDF is not available for download - instead we see this error.

I've used the Nartac configuration tool to make sure the protocols and cipher suites are identical between the two servers.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered the problem out of pure luck.  A separate part of our system was also throwing exceptions, but those exceptions were a bit more explicit, and mentioned the servier's FIPS setting.  After [disabling FIPS](https://www.eonesolutions.com/help-article/this-implementation-is-not-part-of-the-windows-platform-fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms/) on the server in question, and rebooting so that the new setting was in effect, the PDFs started working again.